# kaka consumer offset is not getting deleted after retention

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to test a configuration of broker `offset.retention.minutes=30`. I have changed to this config to 10 mins, instead of 24 hours as default.

however after more than 10 mins the consumer group offset still showing offset in information

```
ldnpsr000001131$ bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper  localhost:2181 --describe -group rent_test
GROUP                          TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             OWNER
rent_test                      rent_test                      0          44              44              0               none
```

Any idea why it is not getting deleted?

Comment: just for clarification, i am using `kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1`,  and the reason that I am testing this case as we are facing the problem of consumer offset lost after a period of inactive consumer group.

Answer (score 0):

`offsets.retention.minutes` controls the log retention window in minutes for offsets topic, namely `__consumer_offsets` into which new consumers store offsets. In your case where you are using the old consumer, the offsets are stored in the zookeeper, so setting `offsets.retention.minutes` has no effect on the ZK-based consumer group.

Comment: i have tried with new consumer, at the same time, I checked the consumer group and found the one as expected.  `ldnpsr000001131$ bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list -new-consumer
rent_test` . However when I stopped consumer, and checked again shown this message `Consumer group `rent_test` does not exist or is rebalancing.`. I was expecting we still can check the consumer offset even there is not active consumer group @amethystic

Comment: Kafka0.10.0.1 only shows information of active groups whereas kafka-consumer-groups.sh in 0.10.2(actually I cannot remember what the exact version introduces the improvement) that has been enhanced a lot is able to show offsets for inacive groups. But there is still a way to check offsets for such groups: looking up __consumer_offsets directly.

Comment: I dont understand why the offset consumer group is not getting delete after retention period after (10 mins) after I changed to use new consumer   of kafka 0.10.0.1 @amethystic

Comment: How did you know that the offsets did not get deleted?

Comment: i did a test. I set the offset retention to 10 mins.
1. Start a producer, and sending number message to a topic
2. start a new consumer to consumer all messages from the topic.
3. check the group consumer offset to make sure the consumer group consumer all message from the topc ( lets say current offset =100)
4. Stop consumer for 30 mins.
5. after 30 mins, sending another set of 100 msgs.
6. start the consumer group againt, observing consumer from offset 100. i was expecting it ONLY the consume message from 201 as the last committed offset should have been removed. @amethystic

Comment: I also checked broker log file, could not seen any log saying the consumer  offset expired or remove  `Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds.` @amethystic

Comment: It might be because of the fact that the offset topic log has only one segment which cannot be deleted by the cleaner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137131/discussion-between-van-and-amethystic).